# Will index on a partition that doesn't include partition column work fast?

Tags: sql-server, index, partitioning, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

Let's say I have a huge table with columns `[CloseOfBusinessDate]`, `[DataSourceID]`, etc.

`[CloseOfBusinessDate]` is a *partition* column and I have a *clustered* index on that column (on `CloseOfBusinessDatePartition`).

If I add an index on the `[DataSourceID]` column on the `CloseOfBusinessDatePartition`, will the following query work fast:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  CloseOfBusinessDate = @cobDate 
  AND DataSourceID    = @dataSourceID
```

I.e., I expect SQL Server to quickly find the right partition and then use the index on the `DataSourceID` column for the fastest results. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that non-unique, non-clustered indexes always include clustered index keys as index key columns.  So your premise is faulty.  The partition key is present in the index, and it may be placed on the same partition scheme as the clustered index.